# i want to get all tweets with specific hashtag

Tags: json, twitter

I've been experimenting with the Twitter API because I want to display a few lists of tweets on a special page.

Among those lists is a list with all tweets containing a specific hashtag (e.g. #نصيحة_ماركتير)

i tried

> [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23نصيحة_ماركتير&result_type=mixed](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23%D9%86%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A9_%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%B1&result_type=mixed)

the result is only recent tweets but i want all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get all the tweets with a specific tag using the Public Twitter API.

What you want to use is Gnip, which is a paid version of the API. It is provided by Twitter and give you access to the entire history of Twitter.